# Trying to replicate POST petition to retrieve youtube comments

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to get the most recents comments from youtube videos, i'm replicating the POST petition as i see from the Firebug plugin.
The response code i get after executing the code is the 403

> The 403 or "Forbidden" error message is a HTTP standard response code
>   indicating that the request was legal and understood but the server
>   refuses to respond to the request.

I'm not quite sure what info i'm missing to successfully get the comments from the video.

```
Map<String, String> cookies =new HashMap<String,String>();
        cookies.put("session_token", session_token);
        cookies.put("page_token", page_token);

Response res= Jsoup.connect(url_comments).header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0")
                    .referrer(linkVideo)
                    .data(cookies)
                    .header("Host", "www.youtube.com")
                    .header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
                    .header("Accept-Language", "es-MX,es-ES;q=0.9,es;q=0.7,es-AR;q=0.6,es-CL;q=0.4,en-US;q=0.3,en;q=0.1")
                    .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
                    .header("X-YouTube-Client-Name", "1")
                    .header("X-YouTube-Client-Version", "1.20161213")
                    .header("X-YouTube-Page-CL", "141992279")
                    .header("X-YouTube-Page-Label", "youtube_20161213_0_RC1")
                    .header("X-YouTube-Variants-Checksum", "a55ebd64c41b17f87231bfa795156a50")
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .header("Cookie", "VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=TRli2T2GQEQ; PREF=cvdm=list&gl=DE&f1=50000000&f5=30; _ga=GA1.2.527380759.1481667156; CONSENT=WP.25af40; YSC=vwoNBo1vTsg; ST-os04us=itct=CAIQ7pgBIhMI1Lef15X30AIVg2ROCh2zVgAw&csn=Bg1TWLXdKoSGuwXKyYzADg")
                    .header("Connection", "keep-alive").ignoreContentType(true)
                    .method(Method.POST).execute();
```

the session_token and page_token is info i get directly from the video webpage. Need help to solve this and get the first comments with the POST petition.

Comment: Are you encoding session_token and page_token?

Comment: @M3SSYM4RV1N what do you mean with encoding?i find them in the html code like this:´EhYSC1U1T2pRQWlpWnh3wAEAyAEA4AEBGAY%3D´ that's the page_token for example.